# Invoke static method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

My project contains this package : `com.X.Y.Z.controller`

This package includes 3 files

ControllerA.java

```
 public class ControllerA {
    public static void insert(Context context, ModelA model) {/*do somethings*/}
  }
```

ControllerB.java

```
 public class ControllerB {
    public static void insert(Context context, ModelB model) {/*do somethings*/}
  }
```

MainController.java

I use following code to invoke insert method from Controller A or B it depends on some condition

```
public static void insert(Context context, Object object) {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(mClass); //Controller A or B
  Method method = clazz.getMethod("insert", ?);
  method.invoke(null, ?);
}
```

how do i pass arguments ? object may be ModelA or ModelB

**I apologize if my wording is not true**

Comment: invoke(Object obj, Object... args) takes as arguments, the object the underlying method is invoked from, and the arguments used for the method call

Comment: You need to call `clazz.getMethod("insert", Context.class, CCC)` where `CCC` is either `ModelA.class` or `ModelB.class`.  But I don't see where you have a way to get the `Model` class.  Will this be passed as a parameter to `insert`, or will there be some other way to obtain it, or do you want to search the class for methods named `insert` and figure out the `Model` class by looking at the method parameters?

Comment: If ModelA and ModelB implement the same interface, for example Model, you can pass Context.class and Model.class as the 2nd and 3rd parameter of getMethod.

Comment: @ajb `ModelA` or `ModelB` Will this be passed as a parameter to `insert`

Comment: Thank you @Howard Wang ,I think this is the best way. But I am still looking for a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:)

ModelA and ModelB implement the same interface, for example Model (not important) ,`model.getClass()` is an important part of his

```
public static void insert(Context context, Model model) {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(mClass); //Controller A or B
  Method method = clazz.getMethod("insert", Context.class, model.getClass());
  method.invoke(null, new Object[]{context, model}));
}
```

Now i can use this :

```
Controller.insert(this, myModelA);
Controller.insert(this, myModelB);
```

**Thanks all**.

Comment: The `invoke()` method is defined to take `Object...` as its arguments, so you don't need to create the array yourself, although it will work.  `method.invoke(null, context, model)` should be equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You pass the classes as varargs in the method lookup and the instance, which is null for a static invocation and the arguments in the invocation:

```
boolean useA = true; // use A or B variant:  
Method m = clazz.getMethod("insert", Context.class, useA ? ModelA.class : ModelB.class);  
m.invoke(null, context, object)
```

Comment: I think he wants to use `object` as the last parameter to the invoked `insert`.  There aren't any variables named `modelA` or `modelB`.  But `invoke` takes a list of `Objects`, so you can just pass `object` as the last parameter and let `invoke()` worry about converting it.